# Google Translate code works some places, not Chrome, but Safari

Tags: javascript, html, css, google-chrome

I've been doing a lot of trial and error with this code. I would appreciate some help. The code gives a Google Translate option for my website header. It works fine on a website I built previously, but not my new one. On Chrome it shows up, but isn't clickable. On Safari it shows up twice. One is clickable and functional. I have cleared caches. Thanks in advance.

```
<div id="google_translate_element"></div>
<script type="text/javascript">
    function googleTranslateElementInit() {
        new google.translate.TranslateElement({pageLanguage: 'no', layout: google.translate.TranslateElement.InlineLayout.SIMPLE}, 'google_translate_element');
    }
</script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="//translate.google.com/translate_a/element.js?cb=googleTranslateElementInit"></script>
```

Comment: I tested your code and works perfectly on chrome. How are you testing it? And if you open the Chrome Javascript Console do you get any errors?

Comment: Thank you so much for your response, Andrea.
Can it be location based? Because this is for a client in Norway, and everywhere were we test here it does not work. When I asked a friend in US, it worked?

Comment: Not sure, but have your checked your Chrome Javascript Console? There must be an error or warning that can help you to debug

Comment: Failed to load resource: net::ERR_BLOCKED_BY_CLIENT
static.doubleclick.net/instream/ad_status.js:1 Failed to load resource: net::ERR_BLOCKED_BY_CLIENT
googleads.g.doubleclick.net/pagead/id:1 Failed to load resource: net::ERR_BLOCKED_BY_CLIENT

Comment: My bet is on an AdBlocker extension. Do you have such extension installed? If so, try to disable it

Comment: It is not adblocker either. Have tried in browser and on phone. Still the same. Could it be something else?

Comment: net::ERR_BLOCKED_BY_CLIENT means that the client (browser) is not loading those addresses. So either an extension or a firewall in your router/network. Nothing else I can think of.

Comment: I have tried different computers and phones. Turned off and removed extensions back and forth. The interesting thing is that on another website I built, with the exact same code, it works perfectly?